# Паузить ajax, при прокрутке страницы пользователем

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Уже пол дня потратил, не могу понять как паузить скрипт при скроллинге пользователя.
С js до этого редко дело имел, склепал как смог.

Вопрос собственно в чем, как паузить скрипты подргузки контента, когда пользователь листает страницу вверх? Но если он бездействует 30-40 секунд, скрип опускается вниз страницы и продолжает обновлять данные. Как это реализовать?

```js
function mode() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'global.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#globalchat').html(data);
                    $("#globalchat").scrollTop(99999999999999999999);
                }
            });
        };
 setInterval(mode, 1000);
 function mode() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'local.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#localchat').html(data);
                    $("#localchat").scrollTop(99999999999999999999);
                }
            });
        };
setInterval(mode, 1000);
function mode() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'private.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#privatechat').html(data);
                    $("#privatechat").scrollTop(99999999999999999999);
                }
            });
        };
setInterval(mode, 1000);
var div = $("#globalchat");
div.scrollTop(div.prop('scrollHeight'));
```

```css
#chats {
        font-size: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size:1920px 1080px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        display: inline;
    }
    #globalchat {
        width: 30%;
        height: 700px;
        display: inline-grid;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    #localchat {
        width: 30%;
        height: 700px;
        display: inline-grid;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    #privatechat {
        width: 30%;
        height: 700px;
        display: inline-grid;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chats">
<!-- начало скрипта php -->
    <div id="globalchat"></div>
    <div id="localchat"></div>
    <div id="privatechat"></div>
    <!-- конец скрипта php -->
</div>
```

Comment: Можно подробнее что именно вы хотите сделать, потому что сейчас это выглядит так, как будто вы каждую секунду отправляете 3 аджакс-запроса и полностью обновляете контент.

Comment: Суть тут в чем, есть лог файл, в нем содержатся данные с сообщениями. Они парсятся через регулярные выражения и выводятся. Все работает как нужно, но есть необходимость при наведении мышки на блок с сообщениями, приостанавливать скрипт, чтобы можно было спокойно листать список скролом.
Поэтому я хочу приостанавливать скрипт, пока мышка находится в блоке, но не понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: С аджаксом работаю впервые, возможно не правильно его использовал.

Comment: По сути подойдет еще вариант, остановки постоянной прокрутки вниз. Если мышь вообще находится в окне браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Гуглил, гуглил и нагуглил
Во первых переделал скрипт аджакса, чтобы скролл не был с ним подвязан.
Вывел скролл в отдельный скрипт, и привязал к циклу с условием. Чтобы если мышь уходила за пределы "body" бесконечно скролило вниз. Но в случае если мышь находится на "body" скролл останавливался.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function mode() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'global.php',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#gchatloader').html(data);
          }
        });
        $.ajax({
          url: 'local.php',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#lchatloader').html(data);
          }
        });
        $.ajax({
          url: 'private.php',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#pchatloader').html(data);

          }
        });
      };
      setInterval(mode, 1000);
    </script>

    *<script>
      var i = 0;
      function func() {
        $("body").mouseover(function() {
          i = 1;
        });
        $("body").mouseout(function() {
          i = 2;
        });
        if (i != 1) {
          $("#pchatloader").scrollTop(99999999999999999999);
          $("#gchatloader").scrollTop(99999999999999999999);
          $("#lchatloader").scrollTop(99999999999999999999);
        }
      }
      setInterval(func, 1000);
    </script>*
```